# Indo-European Etymological Dictionaries Online database (by Brill, Leiden University)

Tags: computational-linguistics, comparative-linguistics, lexicography

> The Indo-European Etymological Dictionaries Online database (by Brill) already includes eleven dictionaries https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/6356/22504

I've read about this "database" before. How do I have to imagine this, how is it structured?

I only found the individual dictionaries on offer for download. That's not a database! However, some of the books do look like compiled from a database.

- Is that one internal with restricted access?
- Is it grafted onto wiktionary (that is, already accessible)?
- Will it ever be finished?

Comment: PS: * Is "Leiden" cognate with "Leeds"? or some of: "London", "Lunt", "Luxemburg", "Lüneburg", "Lichtenberg", "Lauterbach" ...

Answer (score 2):

The databases used to be freely available online, but, some years ago, they were removed and transformed into books. Unfortunately...

Comment: The databases are still available, it’s just they are behind a paywall.